# Android Renderscript create allocation on nexus 7 causes error

Tags: android, renderscript

I trying to convert camera preview frame from YUV format to bitmap with following code:

```
    mYuvToRgbScript = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(mRs, Element.RGBA_8888(mRs));
    final Allocation allocationIn = Allocation.createSized(mRs, Element.U8(mRs),
            (mPreviewWidth * mPreviewHeight) + ((mPreviewHeight / 2) * (mPreviewWidth / 2) * 2));
    allocationIn.copyFrom(mPreviewFrame);

    final Bitmap previewBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mPreviewWidth, mPreviewHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Allocation allocationOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRs, previewBitmap);

    mYuvToRgbScript.setInput(allocationIn);
    mYuvToRgbScript.forEach(allocationOut);

    allocationIn.destroy();
    allocationOut.destroy();

    if (previewBitmap != null) {
        return previewBitmap;
    } else
        return null;
```

This code works ok on 2 phones with android 4.1, but on nexus 7(2013) with android 4.4.3 following lines appears on every preview frame:

```
W/Adreno-RS﹕ <rsdVendorAllocationSetupTexture:647>: ERROR: Runtime texture creation failed err: -10 image: 0x0 alloc: 0xad720000
W/Adreno-RS﹕ <rsdVendorAllocationSetupTexture:649>: ERROR: Runtime texture creation failed type: 8 kind: 0 eleSize: 1
```

And no conversion occurs. With some debugging i located line that causes this log messages:

```
    final Allocation allocationIn = Allocation.createSized(mRs, Element.U8(mRs),
            (mPreviewWidth * mPreviewHeight) + ((mPreviewHeight / 2) * (mPreviewWidth / 2) * 2));
```

Also i tried another allocationIn creation:

```
    final Type.Builder tb = new Type.Builder(mRs, Element.U8(mRs));
    tb.setX(mPreviewFrame.length);
    final Allocation allocationIn = Allocation.createTyped(mRs, tb.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
```

but it causes the same error log lines and no conversion occurs. Any thoughts how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting to copy the allocation back into your preview bitmap. After your call to forEach(), you should do:

```
allocationOut.copyTo(previewBitmap);
```